# How do I make blogspot.com permalinks use Unicode characters?

Tags: blogger, unicode

Most of my post titles on my blog use foreign language text which requires Unicode to show up correctly. When I post with a foreign language title all the Unicode characters are completely deleted from the permalink and I'm left with something generic like "post-6.html". What can I do? I'm using Blogger in the United States.

Answer (score 1):

From Blogger Post Editor, you can customize your posts with custom permalinks setting. If you prefer to use a custom permalink, you can do so via the “Permalink” option in the Post Settings box.

example www.nameofblog.blogspot.com/2012/06/**post-6**.html .

[image: Add custom permalink path on Blogger]

The bolded area is the portion of the URL that is customizable.

If the custom permalink you entered already exists, Blogger will attempt find a free one for you.

At present, the characters allowed in a custom URL are limited to: a-z, A-Z, 0-1. The only special characters available are underscore, dash, and period.

You can [read here](https://blogger.googleblog.com/2012/07/customize-your-posts-with-permalinks.html) for more details about it.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe there is any way to make Blogger do this.